# Invalid argument after upgrading geth from 1.5.9 to 1.6.1

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, gas-estimate, upgrading

Once upgraded the geth node to 1.6.1 it is not accepting queries anymore, throwing the following error:

```
Invalid argument 0: missing 0x prefix for hex data
```

That's weird for a query like this, where argument 0 seems to be a "from address" that starts with 0x.

```
eth_estimateGas([{ "from": "0x8c60d40a2e848251d139fc2b0b6b770bb3351ffd", "to": "0xe5f68950d479fab12797dabbe5a4b0d88ec7a722", "value": "1000000000000000000", "data": "0x4d61726b65745061792e696f202d204661756365743a2053656e642066756e647320746f203078653566363839353064343739666162313237393764616262653561346230643838656337613732322c2031206574686572" }])
```

Why this error? Why not in previous versions? Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems new geth versions require every integer value must be in hex format. So,

```
"value": "1000000000000000000"
```

is wrong syntax. It should be:

```
"value": "0xde0b6b3a7640000"
```

instead.